# Trying to create a TFS server 2012 to store all source code and documentation delivered from vendor

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, configuration-management

I am trying to create a TFS where I can store Source code and documentation of each release sent by vendor. I created three environment ( dev, UAT, prod). once new release is sent using branching I promote the previous version in dev to UAT and version in UAT to Prod. How far is this reliable . If later in future I want to get the code for particular version can I get it?

Comment: "How far is this reliable". Not sure what exactly you are trying to do here. Provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

> If later in future I want to get the code for particular version can I
>   get it?

Yes you can get any version of the code by Changeset, DateTime or Label. You can right click on any folder in Source Control Explorer --> Advanced --> Get Specific Version and then you can select any of the above options and get code for that version.

Comment: It depends on what you are using it for. As I said in the answer you can get it by changeset, Datetime or label. If you want the version that is installed to Prod you should get it from the prod branch. You can label each version that is pushed to prod and then later get it using the label.

Comment: It works. Trying to add documentation , installation files and source code in different folders in a project as they are delivered. But to huge data I cannot check it into single changeset.What is the best way to Put it all in one changeset so that in future when I want a specific version its easy to get it.

Comment: I understand that we can get it by label  or changeset but my question is how can we get specific verison of source , documentation and installation files together

Comment: You can check it in as separate changesets if you have to and then label that version (say Release X) and then when you get it using that label you will get the version.

Comment: I tried using label but the thing is if we are deleting any file then the label gets deleted. Is there any option rather than using label?

Comment: You should use label at the top level not the file level. Then deleting file should not delete the label

Comment: Yes. But still there is an option to delete the label in find label which may cause deleting the label by anyone.

Comment: Yes that's true. In that case have following options: 1) when you merge the changes from Dev to UAt/Prod check it in as a single changeset and use that to get the files 2) use Datetime to get the files (not recommended) 3) create a new branch everything to push anything to Prod(lot of teams do this)

Comment: In my case I already have Dev branched to QA and QA to production. So all I need to do is put the latest delivery to dev and then merge whatever was within dev to QA , QA to prod. Once I do merging I cannot put all of that in a single changeset to check in  because of large amount of data.